# What are the advantages of anonymous arrays in Perl?

Tags: perl, reference

What are the advantages of anonymous array in Perl?

Comment: This question does not make much sense. It's like asking "what are the advantages of numbers?" or "what are the advantages of variables?" or something like that... If you have a specific example in mind, please share it with us, and we might be able to explain why an anonymous array was used.

Comment: I'd answer this if the question were open.

Comment: @briandfoy Voted to reopen then. It's an interesting and informative topic, I wish the question altogether was better.

Comment: One advantage is that they can be used as part of a hash or another array. In this way you can build things like hashes of arrays or arrays of arrays. See [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information

Comment: @Nizam what leads you to ask this question?  Give some more background

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Named arrays can also be used in HoA and AoA, though, so that's not really an advantage of anonymous arrays. (Anonymous arrays make it much easier to build those structures dynamically, but they're not required, provided you make a large enough number of named arrays.)

Comment: If the order of the data is important, use an array. Otherwise use a hash.

Answer (score 10):

Array references—which anonymous arrays are one type of—allows Perl to treat the array as a single item. This allows you to build complex, nested data structures as well. This applies to hash, code, and all the other reference types too, but here I'll show only the hash reference. You can read [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com) for much more.

For the immediate, literal question, consider that there are two ways to make an array: with a named variable, and without a named variable ("anonymous"):

```
my @named_array = ( 1, 3, 7 );

[ 1, 3, 7 ];
```

The first line takes a list and stores it in a named array variable. You are probably used to seeing that everywhere.

That second line, `[ 1, 3, 7 ]`, doesn't do anything. It's just a value.

But, consider this analogue, where you store a scalar value in a scalar variable (overloaded use of "scalar" there), and the next line that is just the value:

```
my $number = 6;

6;
```

Now here's the trick. You know that you can pass a scalar variable to a subroutine. You could write that as this:

```
my $number = 6;
some_sub( $number );
```

But why bother with the variable at all if that's the only use of it? Get rid of it altogether and pass the value directly:

```
some_sub( 6 );
```

It's the same thing with anonymous references. You can make the named version first and take a reference to it:

```
my @array = ( 1, 3, 7 );
some_sub( \@array );
```

But just like the scalar example, you don't need to clutter your code with a named array if it's only there so you can get a reference to it. Just make the reference directly:

```
some_sub( [ 1, 3, 7 ] );
```

But there's more to the story, and you have to know a little about how Perl works to understand it.

### Why references at all?

Perl is mostly built around scalars (single item) and lists (multiple items). A scalar variable holds a scalar value, and an array variable hold a list (see [What’s the difference between a list and an array?](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/01/whats-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array/)).

There are many features where you can use only a scalar, including single list elements, hash keys, and hash values:

```
$array[$i] = $single_item;
$hash{$single_item} = $other_single_item;
```

Other places that are always a list, such as the argument list to a subroutine:

```
sub some_sub {
    my @args = @_;
    ...
    }
```

Even if you call `some_sub` with two arrays, you end up with a single list stored in `@_`. You can't tell where `@array_1` stopped and `@array_2` started. This is all one list whose size is the combined sizes of the two arrays:

```
some_sub( @array_1, @array_2 );
```

Reference are a way to treat something as a single item. When you get that single item, you *dereference* it to get back to the original.

This means that you can store a array reference as a hash value:

```
$hash{$key} = \@some_array; # ref to named variable
$hash{$key} = [ 1, 3, 7 ];  # anonymous array directly
```

Or, you can create a list where each item is an array reference rather than the single, "flat" list you saw before:

```
my @Array_of_Arrays = ( \@array_1, \@array_2 , [1,3,7], ... );
my $seventh_of_ninth = $Array_of_Arrays[9][7];
```

The [Perl Data Structures Cookbook (perldsc)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) has many examples of different sorts of complex data structures which you build with references.

You can pass references to subroutines so the array elements don't mix. This argument list is exactly two elements, and inside the subroutine you know which array you are dealing with:

```
some_sub( \@array_1, \@array_2 );
```

If you were curious about another aspect of this, you can update your question.